# Prove that ordinals are comparable

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

There is one important theorem about ordinals, which says if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals, then either $\alpha\in\beta$, or $\alpha=\beta$, or $\beta\in\alpha$.

The preceding lemma states that either $\alpha\cap\beta=\alpha$ or $\alpha\cap\beta=\beta$, which is used in the proof of this theorem.

Proof: Suppose $\alpha\neq\beta$, then either $\alpha\subset\beta$ or $\beta\subset\alpha$, where $A\subset B$ means $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.
But how does $\alpha\subset\beta$ imply $\alpha\in\beta$?

Comment: How do you define ordinals? That would be a crucial part in proving that since $\alpha\subset\beta$ does not imply $\alpha\in\beta$ in general.

Comment: Where are you proving this fact: $\alpha \neq \beta \implies \alpha \subset \beta \lor \beta \subset \alpha$?

Comment: $x$ is an ordinal if it is transitive, i.e. $\forall y\in x$, $y\subset x$, and $x$ is strictly well ordered by $\in$.

Comment: Look at the set $\beta \setminus \alpha$. This is a subset of $\beta$ and thus well-ordered. What can you say about its minimal element?

Comment: Let $x$ be the least element in $\beta\setminus\alpha$, then $x\subseteq\alpha$.  But why is $\alpha\subseteq x$?

Comment: @SidCaroline I have edited my answer. Does my answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 1):

We show $\alpha \subset \beta \implies \alpha \in \beta$
Let $x$ be the $\in$ minimal element of $\beta \setminus \alpha$.

Let $\gamma$ be in $x$. If $\gamma$ is not in $\alpha$ then $\gamma$ is in $\beta \setminus \alpha$ by transitivity of $\in$. This is a contradiction to $x%$ being $\in$ minimal in $\beta \setminus \alpha$. This shows $x\subseteq \alpha$.

Let $\delta$ be in $\alpha$. Since there is no ordinal in $\beta \setminus \alpha$ that is in $x$, any ordinal in $x$ must be a member of $\alpha$, since by assumption, $\alpha \subset \beta$ and since $x \in \beta$, $x \subset \beta$. We prove $\delta \in x$.

Assume $\delta \not \in x$. Since $\delta$ is not equal to $x$, there is an $x_1 \in x\setminus \delta$. Now,  $\delta \not \in x_1$, otherwise, by transitivity of $\in$, $\delta \in x$. Also, $x_1$ cannot be equal to $\delta$, because then $\delta \in x$. So there is an element of $x_1$, say $x_2$ that is not in $\delta$. Continue this reasoning infinitely, you obtain a sequence of ordinals $x_k$, that has no $\in$ minimal element, a contradiction to the well-foundedness of $\in$. Thus $\delta \in x$.

Now $x=\alpha$, and $x\in \beta$ shows $\alpha \in \beta$.

Comment: But how can you choose an ordinal to be the mininum of $x$ and $\delta$ without assuming that ordinals are comparable which is what we are trying to prove?

Comment: I can't understand this proof.

Comment: Hi Timothy, what part do you not understand?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if you find something that does not make sense, thank you.

Comment: @SidCaroline The answer is correct-- we only use wellfoundedness of $\in$.

Comment: Beginner here. In that second line of paragraph 2 I don't understand how $\gamma$ not being in $\alpha$ implies that $\gamma\in\beta\backslash\alpha$ by the transitivity of $\in$ - The transitivity of $\in$ applies for elements of a given ordinal. So what is the ordinal in question?

Answer (score 1):

For given ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the following claims hold true:

1. $\alpha\subsetneq\beta\implies\alpha\in\beta$. (I presented a proof for this at [If $\alpha\ne\beta$ are ordinals and $\alpha\subset\beta$ show $\alpha\in\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983906/if-alpha-ne-beta-are-ordinals-and-alpha-subset-beta-show-alpha-in-beta/2845626#2845626))
2. $\alpha\cap \beta$ is an ordinal. (It's quite easy to prove this)

For $\alpha=\beta$, the theorem is trivially true. For $\alpha\neq\beta$, let $z=\alpha\cap\beta$, hence $z$ is an ordinal. We will prove this case by contradiction.

Assume $\alpha\not\subsetneq\beta$ and $\beta\not\subsetneq\alpha$. Since $z\subsetneq\alpha$ and $z$ is an ordinal, then $z\in\alpha$. Similarly, $z\in\beta$. Thus $z\in\alpha\cap\beta=z$, which contradicts the fact that $z$ is ordinal and hence well-ordered under $\in$. As a result, either $\alpha\subsetneq\beta$ or $\beta\subsetneq\alpha$.