# Comparing ordinal sizes

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, set-theory

I was trying to understand the proof to the following theorem, specifically (iii). (The same theorem is listed here: [Prove that ordinals are comparable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486996/prove-that-ordinals-are-comparable), but the proofs seem to be different.)

> Suppose $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are ordinals. Then, (iii) exactly one of $\alpha<\beta, \alpha=\beta, \beta<\alpha$ holds, and (iv) if $X$ is a non-empty set of ordinals, then $X$ has a least element $\delta$ and $\delta=\bigcap X$.

Proof:
(iii) Certainly we already know that no more than one of these holds. Consider $\alpha \cap \beta .$ This is also an ordinal (see (iv), or do as exercise). If, for example $\alpha \cap \beta=\alpha$ then $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ and so $\alpha \leq \beta .$ So for a contradiction, suppose $\alpha \cap \beta$ is a proper subset of both $\alpha$ and $\beta .$ Thus (by a previous lemma) $\alpha \cap \beta \in \alpha$ and $\alpha \cap \beta \in \beta .$ So $\alpha \cap \beta \in \alpha \cap \beta:$ a contradiction.

I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding this proof.

1. Why does $\alpha \cap \beta \in \alpha$ and $\alpha \cap \beta \in \beta$ imply that $\alpha \cap \beta \in \alpha \cap \beta$ ? Surely, $\alpha \cap \beta \subset \alpha$, $\alpha \cap \beta \subset \beta$ implies that $\alpha \cap \beta \subseteq \alpha \cap \beta$, and not necessarily $\alpha \cap \beta \subset \alpha \cap \beta$? (In this course, $\subset$ means a strict subset)
2. I don't comprehend what the argument is. I get that if $\alpha \cap \beta=\alpha$, then $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ and so $\alpha \leq \beta .$ But what does this contribute to proving the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By definition of intersection, any element $x$ satisfies $x\in\alpha\cap\beta\iff x\in\alpha\land x\in\beta$. This is applied to $x=\alpha\cap\beta$.
2. We have proved that $\alpha\cap\beta$ can't be a proper subset of both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, thus either $\alpha\cap\beta=\alpha$, that is, $\alpha\le\beta$ or $\alpha\cap\beta=\beta$, that is, $\beta\le\alpha$ must hold.
   Stating otherwise, if $\alpha\ne\beta$ then either $\alpha<\beta$ or $\beta<\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

1. For any $x$, $A$ and $B$, if $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, then $x \in A \cap B$. The statement you are querying is an instance of that (with $x = \alpha \cap \beta$, $A = \alpha$ and $B = \beta$).
2. I think words "for example" in the text of the proof are a bit misleading. The form of the argument is that one of the following must hold:
   $$
   \begin{array}{cl}
   \mbox{(a)} & \alpha \cap \beta = \alpha\\
   \mbox{(b)} & \alpha \cap \beta = \beta \\
   \mbox{(c)} & \alpha \cap \beta \subsetneq \alpha \mbox{ and } \alpha \cap \beta \subsetneq \beta
   \end{array}
   $$

The "for example" statement is saying that to deal with (a) and (b) , it is sufficient, by symmetry, just to consider (a).